# Property Injection (setter injection) Prism for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism

Is the setter injection supported in the Xamarin.forms?

I have a service injected in the bootstrapper like this

```
Container.RegisterType<ICommonService, CommonService>();
```

And inside a viewmodel, I want to have an instance injected to a property like this

```
[Dependency]
public ICommonService CommonService { get; set; }
```

But in the runtime, the property CommonService is always null.

The attribute I used is the Microsoft.Practices.Unity.DependencyAttribute, not Xamarin.Forms.DependencyAttribute

If I inject inside the constructor, it works

```
public LandingPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ICommonService commonService)
```

Edited: added code snippet

```
    public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override Page CreateMainPage()
    {
        try
        {
            return Container.Resolve<Views.LandingPage>();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //TODO: intent to get exception info
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        DependencyResolver.Instance.Initialize(Container);

        this.RegisterViews();

        this.RegisterServices();

        this.RegisterSingleton();

    }

    private void RegisterViews()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LandingPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Page1>();
    }

    private void RegisterServices()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<ICommonService, CommonService>();
    }

    private void RegisterSingleton()
    {

    }
}

 public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run(this);
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor injection is preferred above property injection, so if constructor injection why change this?

Comment: @Ric, each single feature has its own purpose of use, the point is when to use and how we design right, this link can help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649447.aspx section "When to Use Property (Setter) Injection", thanks

Comment: Do you really need INavigationService navigationService ?

Comment: I am sure I get your question, the navigationservice is just an example using constructor injection, basically we can inject multiple dependencies there, that is working. My question is if the "property injection" supported, if it isn't, then I'll switch to an alternative. I 'bingle' around, it looks like the xamarin.forms doesn't support. thanks.

Comment: I believe you did it correctly, Juts for double check what is the function that you placed your Container.RegisterType is it in protected override void RegisterTypes() ?.

Comment: I am using Prism, I put the "register types" part inside the bootstrapper. I also edited my question to add more code snippet, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm they removed the `DependencyAttribute` injection feature since Prism 7.0, I think we should register it manually. (your code snippet should work)

Look: https://brianlagunas.com/whats-new-in-prism-for-xamarin-forms-7-0/

[image: BrianLagunas Prism 7.0 changes]